# Tomcat .Zip File Failed to Start

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have downloaded tomcat 6.0.Zip file and unzipped in Tomcat Folder. and i have Setted mt Catiline_Home and Java_Home. and started my Tomcat6.exe file

It has Failed To start,it showing error ,what i need to do,i am new to these thing please help me to start my Tomcat service

```
"The specified Service Doesnt not exist as Installed service
Unable to open tomcat6 service
```

Comment: Usually you would go into your tomcat "bin" directory and run "startup", not the exe file. May want to specify whether this is linux or windows based as well.

Comment: Yes, i started up StartUp.bat file, still not working, i am using windows Xp 32 bit

Comment: What is it saying when you run "catalina.bat start"??

Comment: It Showing the window with following error"The specified Service Doesnt not exist as Installed service
Unable to open tomcat6 service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tomcat folder might be for 64 bit computer and your system might be 32 bit or the other way round.Check that and download the tomcat folder for 32 bit or 64 bit, as per your system configurations.